# Timeout in what units

Tags: connection, timeout, qpython

Is the timeout in qpython.qconnection.QConnection in any specific units, or it is just non-dimentional number?

From my experience, number 3000.0 corresponds roughly to 20 seconds.

Ref:

[Timeout in qconnection.QConnection](https://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/qpython.html#qpython.qconnection.QConnection)

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I was wondering the same thing.

If you look in the [source code](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython/blob/master/qpython/qconnection.py), the `timeout` argument of the `QConnection` constructor is supplied to a `socket.settimeout()` call.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) for the `socket.settimeout()` method, you will see that it is a timeout in seconds.